# not getting formatted_address from google place API

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, autocomplete, google-places-api

```
useEffect(() => {
    autoCompleteRef.current = new window.google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputRef.current, options);
    autoCompleteRef.current.addListener('place_changed', async function () {
      const place = await autoCompleteRef.current.getPlace();
      console.log('Selected Place: ', place);

      const address = place.address_components;
      const extractedAddress = {
        streetName: address.find((comp) => comp.types.includes('route'))?.long_name || '',
        city: address.find((comp) => comp.types.includes('locality'))?.long_name || '',
        province:
          address.find((comp) => comp.types.includes('administrative_area_level_1'))?.long_name ||
          '',
        country: address.find((comp) => comp.types.includes('country'))?.long_name || '',
        countryCode: address.find((comp) => comp.types.includes('country'))?.short_name || '',
        postalCode: address.find((comp) => comp.types.includes('postal_code'))?.long_name || '',
        fullAddress: place.formatted_address || '',
      };

      setExtractedAddress(extractedAddress);
    });
  }, []);
```

In the above code why I am fullAddress as empty string

tried all the methods available

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Which reproduces your issue so that the community can play around in it and check what might be causing your issue.